# Delete other users' files in shared folders using Google Drive v3 API

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

We use a Google Drive shared folder to allow multiple contributors to upload files for processing. I have written a API v3 client to retrieve the files and do what I need to do with them. My problem is how to get rid of those files after I'm done. I can't find a way to either delete the file or move it to the original users Trash folder on files I don't own (permission denied errors). Is there a way to handle something like this via the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do pretty much anything to shared files, except delete them :-)

So you could remove the shared folder from the file's parents, so it's no longer visible to the central user. If your users create a folder called say "files that can be deleted", which is shared to you, you could move the file there so your users can do their own housekeeping. 
You can also update its contents with a zero length body so it no longer consumes any quota, but note that previous versions are retained and will consume quota until Google purges them.

Comment: Thanks pinoyyid, that's what I was afraid of. Replacing with a 0 byte body is an excellent idea and will address most of the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that you can do in this instance.

The first is request that the user grant your client access to the files when they upload the file. Considering that the file is being uploaded to a central shared location all the files should actually be owned by the account that is managing it.

Another option would be to use a service account to upload the files this way the service account would automatically own the files all actions should be preformed by it.

Comment: We have multiple non-profit volunteers uploading files into the shared folder. Not sure what else they can do to "grant access". The files remain owned by the uploader. The service account has some access; it can remove them from the UI (which dumps them out of the shared folder into "unorganized" state, not freeing up the space), but trying to delete via the API gives the permission denied error. Service account defeats the purpose of a place for volunteers to put files...

Comment: The user grants access by sharing the file with the service account like you would share a file with any other user.   You can also give these people an application which users the service account to upload the file.